# Transaction for collection

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

How can I do using transacting t, I want to make sure the row is successful remove before saving the record:

```
var Roles = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
     model: Role
);

Role.where('name', '=', 'Staff').destroy();

var roles = Roles.forge([{name: 'Staff'}, {name: 'Guest'}]);

Promise.all(roles.invoke('save')).then(function(role) {
    resolve(role);
}).catch(function (err) {
    reject({"status":"error", "data": err});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just use Bookshelf's `transaction()` method.

But first your `save()` MUST be in the context of the `destroy()` promise, so ensuring proper sequence, otherwise you risk having your saved data being also deleted by the destroy.

So it may look like:

```
var Roles = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Role
});

bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
  return Role
    .where('name', '=', 'Staff')
    .destroy({transacting: t})
    .then(function() {
      var roles = Roles.forge([{name: 'Staff'}, {name: 'Guest'}]);
      return roles
        .invokeThen('save', null, {transacting: t});
    });
});
```